# Doctrine many-to-many relations with extra field

Tags: php, schema, yaml, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I want to join 3 table, Szamla, Termek and Vasarlo.

This is my schema:

```
options:
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8

Szamla:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    datum:
      type: timestamp
      notnull: true
    total:
      type: float
      notnull: true
    fizetesi_datum:
      type: date
    fizetesi_ora:
      type: time
    teljesites:
      type: timestamp
    user_id:
      type: int(10)
      notnull: true
    afa:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0
  relations:
    SzamlaTermekek:
      class: Termek
      local: szamla_id
      foreign: termek_id
      refClass: SzamlaTermek

Vasarlo:
  columns:
    nev:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    varos:
      type: string(200)
      notnull: true
    utca:
      type: string(200)
      notnull: true
    zip:
      type: string(10)
      notnull: true
    email:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    orszh:
      type: string(4)
      notnull: true
    krzt:
      type: string(2)
      notnull: true
    telszama:
      type: string(4)
      notnull: true
    telszamb:
      type: string(3)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    Szamlak:
      class: Szamla
      type: many
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      foreignAlias: Vasarlo

Termek:
  columns:
    nev:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    leiras:
      type: string(500)
      notnull: true
    ar:
      type: float
      notnull: true
    raktar:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
      default: Dunaújváros
    raktaron:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    zarolt:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    jotallas:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    garancia:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    slider:
      type: integer(1)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    SzamlaTermekek:
      class: Szamla
      local: termek_id
      foreign: szamla_id
      refClass: SzamlaTermek

SzamlaTermek:
  columns:
    szamla_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    termek_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    number:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
      default: 1
```

The query:

```
   $query = Doctrine_Core::getTable($table)->createQuery('s');
    $query->leftJoin('Vasarlo v');
    $query->leftJoin('SzamlaTermekek t');
    $result = $query->fetchArray();
```

The result is ok, but the number from SzamlaTermek needed. How get i the number field too? Without select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
->select('t.number')
```

like

```
$query->select('t.number')
       ->leftJoin('Vasarlo v')
       ->leftJoin('SzamlaTermekek t');
```

Comment: without select you can join all tables but you get all the fields from all 3 tables

Comment: like :  Doctrine_Query::create()->from('table a')->leftJoin('Vasarlo v')->leftJoin('SzamlaTermekek t');

Comment: Yes, with Symfony: Doctrine_Core::getTable('Szamla')->createQuery('s')->leftJoin('Vasarlo v')->leftJoin('SzamlaTermekek t')->fetchArray(); The solution something like this:Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Szamla')->leftJoin('Szamla.Vasarlo v')->leftJoin('Szamla.SzamlaTermekek t')->leftJoin('t.SzamlaTermek szt ON t.id = szt.termek_id AND Szamla.id = szt.szamla_id INDEXBY szt.termek_id');